# Scope of using keyword in header/implementation files

Tags: c++

I am trying to grasp the appropriate use of the `using` keyword in the header files.

For instance, assuming that I have the following:

```
/* Dummy.hpp */
#include "path/to/Target.hpp"

class Dummy
{                                         // Target is a class
  using Target = namespace_a::namespace_b:Target

public:

  Dummy(Target object, int ID);
  virtual ~Dummy();

private:

  Target _target;
  int    _ID;
}
```

As my header file. And then, I implement the `.cpp` file as:

```
/* Dummy.cpp */
#include "path/to/Dummy.hpp"

             //prob here
Dummy::Dummy(Target object, int ID)
:_target(object),
_ID(ID)
{}

Dummy::~Dummy() = default;
```

I have to re-declare the `using Target =  namespace_a::namespace_b::Target` statement that I have in my `.hpp` file. Isn't there a way to use it only once, namely use it only in the `.hpp` file and extend its scope to the `.cpp` file?

Comment: `Dummy::Dummy(Dummy::Target`?

Comment: Create a [mcve] Why do you think there is a "prob" there?

Comment: @ex1led `using Target` is an alias private to the `Dummy` class; just place it outside the class if you want it to be accessible in your `cpp` file.